# How can I alphabetize a unique result in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I'm generating a list based on using the `UNIQUE` function.

How can I get the output to be alphabetized automatically?

Comment: Also check out this answer, which uses `=query(...` to take the place of `unique` and sorts based on another column: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35384/79827

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Sort and Unique together.

```
=sort(unique(A:A))
```

Here are the descriptions of the [filter functions](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240287) for Google spreadsheets.

Comment: As was already [noted by clement_thirode](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84213/88163), using `A:A` will return also blank cells. It's better to use a reference just for the required cells, but in some cases the formula by clemment_thirode could be better.

Answer (score 4):

I add a filter function to keep only cells with data.

```
=sort(filter(unique(A:A);unique(A:A)<>""))
```

Maybe it could help.

Comment: Brief answers are fine but if you explain how your formula works it will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this for more readability.

```
=sort(unique(filter(A:A, not(isblank(A:A)))))
```